# Cleaning up packages installed globally

Tags: pip, anaconda, conda, package-managers

I've been using Anaconda as my package manager but was unaware that it is recommended to install additional packages within virtual environments rather than globally. As a result, I've been installing all packages in my base environment by simply opening a terminal window and running commands such as:

> pip3 install requests_html

> conda install sklearn

This seemed to work fine for a while until I recently decided to try updating my packages. I tried running

> conda update --all

which then provided a list of all the packages that will be updated. However, it also said that some packages will be downgraded instead, which after some googling seems to be due to version conflicts which is why environments are recommended.

Sample output:

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: /Users/mahuja/opt/anaconda3


The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    _anaconda_depends-2020.07  |           py38_0           6 KB
    anaconda-custom            |           py38_1          35 KB
    anaconda-navigator-1.10.0  |           py38_0         6.2 MB
    anaconda-project-0.9.1     |     pyhd3eb1b0_1         215 KB
    appdirs-1.4.4              |             py_0          13 KB
    appnope-0.1.2              |py38hecd8cb5_1001          10 KB
    argon2-cffi-20.1.0         |   py38haf1e3a3_1          44 KB
    asn1crypto-1.4.0           |             py_0          80 KB
    
    backports-1.0              |     pyhd3eb1b0_2         210 KB
    backports.functools_lru_cache-1.6.1|     pyhd3eb1b0_0          12 KB
    backports.shutil_get_terminal_size-1.0.0|     pyhd3eb1b0_3          10 KB
    backports.tempfile-1.0     |     pyhd3eb1b0_1          11 KB
    beautifulsoup4-4.9.3       |     pyha847dfd_0          86 KB
    bitarray-1.6.3             |   py38h9ed2024_1          92 KB
    black-19.10b0              |             py_0          86 KB
    bleach-3.2.2               |     pyhd3eb1b0_0         113 KB
    blosc-1.20.1               |       hab81aa3_0          56 KB
    bokeh-2.2.3                |           py38_0         5.3 MB
    brotli-1.0.9               |       hb1e8313_2         398 KB
    brotlipy-0.7.0             |py38h9ed2024_1003         331 KB
    gevent-21.1.1              |   py38h9ed2024_1         1.5 MB
    giflib-5.1.4               |       h1de35cc_1          59 KB
    glib-2.66.1                |       h9bbe63b_0         2.7 MB
    glob2-0.7                  |     pyhd3eb1b0_0          12 KB
    greenlet-0.4.17            |   py38haf1e3a3_0          20 KB
    idna-2.10                  |     pyhd3eb1b0_0          52 KB
    imagecodecs-2021.1.11      |   py38h2ea9c00_1         5.4 MB
    importlib-metadata-2.0.0   |             py_1          35 KB
    importlib_metadata-2.0.0   |                1          11 KB
    iniconfig-1.1.1            |     pyhd3eb1b0_0           8 KB
    intervaltree-3.1.0         |             py_0          26 KB
    ipykernel-5.3.4            |   py38h5ca1d4c_0         180 KB
    ipython-7.19.0             |   py38h01d92e1_1         991 KB
    ipython_genutils-0.2.0     |     pyhd3eb1b0_1          27 KB
    ipywidgets-7.6.3           |     pyhd3eb1b0_1         105 KB
    isort-5.6.4                |             py_0          78 KB
    jedi-0.17.2                |   py38hecd8cb5_1         923 KB
    jinja2-2.11.2              |     pyhd3eb1b0_0          93 KB
    joblib-1.0.0               |     pyhd3eb1b0_0         208 KB
    jsonschema-3.2.0           |             py_2          47 KB
    jupyter_client-6.1.7       |             py_0          77 KB
    jupyter_console-6.2.0      |             py_0          26 KB
    jupyter_core-4.7.0         |   py38hecd8cb5_0          68 KB
    jupyterlab-2.2.6           |             py_0         3.4 MB
    jupyterlab_pygments-0.1.2  |             py_0           8 KB
    jupyterlab_widgets-1.0.0   |     pyhd3eb1b0_1         109 KB
    jxrlib-1.1                 |       haf1e3a3_2         206 KB
    matplotlib-base-3.3.2      |   py38h181983e_0         5.1 MB
    mkl_fft-1.2.0              |   py38hc64f4ea_0         143 KB
    mock-4.0.3                 |     pyhd3eb1b0_0          29 KB
    more-itertools-8.6.0       |     pyhd3eb1b0_0          40 KB
    msgpack-python-1.0.1       |   py38hf7b0b51_0          75 KB
    mypy_extensions-0.4.3      |           py38_0           9 KB
    nbclient-0.5.1             |             py_0          58 KB
    nbconvert-6.0.7            |           py38_0         483 KB
    nbformat-5.1.2             |     pyhd3eb1b0_1          68 KB
    nest-asyncio-1.4.3         |     pyhd3eb1b0_0          11 KB
    networkx-2.5               |             py_0         1.1 MB
    nose-1.3.7                 |  pyhd3eb1b0_1006         128 KB
    notebook-6.2.0             |   py38hecd8cb5_0         4.1 MB
    numba-0.51.2               |   py38h6440ff4_1         3.1 MB
    numexpr-2.7.2              |   py38h16bde0e_0         120 KB
    numpy-1.19.2               |   py38h456fd55_0          21 KB
    numpy-base-1.19.2          |   py38hcfb5961_0         4.0 MB
    numpydoc-1.1.0             |     pyhd3eb1b0_1          42 KB
    openjpeg-2.3.0             |       hb95cd4c_1         281 KB
    openpyxl-3.0.6             |     pyhd3eb1b0_0         159 KB
    openssl-1.1.1i             |       h9ed2024_0         2.2 MB
    packaging-20.8             |     pyhd3eb1b0_0          36 KB
    pandas-1.2.1               |   py38hb2f4e1b_0         8.3 MB
    pandoc-2.11                |       h0dc7051_0        10.8 MB
    pandocfilters-1.4.3        |   py38hecd8cb5_1          14 KB
    path-15.0.1                |   py38hecd8cb5_0          37 KB
    path.py-12.5.0             |                0           4 KB
    pathlib2-2.3.5             |   py38hecd8cb5_2          38 KB
    pathspec-0.7.0             |             py_0          26 KB
    pexpect-4.8.0              |     pyhd3eb1b0_3          53 KB
    pickleshare-0.7.5          |  pyhd3eb1b0_1003          13 KB
    pillow-8.1.0               |   py38h5270095_0         590 KB
    pip-20.3.3                 |   py38hecd8cb5_0         1.8 MB
    pkginfo-1.7.0              |   py38hecd8cb5_0          43 KB
    prometheus_client-0.9.0    |     pyhd3eb1b0_0          45 KB
    prompt-toolkit-3.0.8       |             py_0         248 KB
    prompt_toolkit-3.0.8       |                0          12 KB
    psutil-5.7.2               |   py38haf1e3a3_0         341 KB
    ptyprocess-0.7.0           |     pyhd3eb1b0_2          17 KB
    py-1.10.0                  |     pyhd3eb1b0_0          76 KB
    pycurl-7.43.0.6            |   py38hddc9c9b_0          66 KB
    pydocstyle-5.1.1           |             py_0          38 KB
    pyerfa-1.7.1.1             |   py38h9ed2024_1         296 KB
    pygments-2.7.4             |     pyhd3eb1b0_0         676 KB
    pylint-2.6.0               |           py38_0         438 KB
    pyls-black-0.4.6           |       hd3eb1b0_0           9 KB
    pyls-spyder-0.3.0          |     pyhd3eb1b0_0          10 KB
    pyopenssl-20.0.1           |     pyhd3eb1b0_1          49 KB
    pyparsing-2.4.7            |     pyhd3eb1b0_0          59 KB
    pyrsistent-0.17.3          |   py38haf1e3a3_0          89 KB
    pytest-6.2.1               |   py38hecd8cb5_0         427 KB
    python-3.8.5               |       h26836e1_1        20.6 MB
    python-jsonrpc-server-0.4.0|             py_0          12 KB
    python-language-server-0.36.2|     pyhd3eb1b0_0          41 KB
    python-libarchive-c-2.9    |     pyhd3eb1b0_0          46 KB
    python.app-3               |   py38h9ed2024_0          20 KB
    pytz-2020.5                |     pyhd3eb1b0_0         182 KB
    pywavelets-1.1.1           |   py38haf1e3a3_2         3.4 MB
    pyyaml-5.4.1               |   py38h9ed2024_1         165 KB
    pyzmq-20.0.0               |   py38h23ab428_1         405 KB
    qtawesome-1.0.1            |             py_0         757 KB
    qtconsole-4.7.7            |             py_0          96 KB
    regex-2020.11.13           |   py38h9ed2024_0         310 KB
    requests-2.25.1            |     pyhd3eb1b0_0          52 KB
    ripgrep-12.1.1             |                0         1.3 MB
    rope-0.18.0                |             py_0         126 KB
    scikit-image-0.17.2        |   py38h81aa140_0         8.9 MB
    scikit-learn-0.23.2        |   py38h959d312_0         4.7 MB
    scipy-1.5.2                |   py38h2515648_0        13.3 MB
    seaborn-0.11.1             |     pyhd3eb1b0_0         212 KB
    send2trash-1.5.0           |     pyhd3eb1b0_1          14 KB
    setuptools-51.3.3          |   py38hecd8cb5_4         727 KB
    singledispatch-3.4.0.3     |          py_1001          12 KB
    six-1.15.0                 |   py38hecd8cb5_0          27 KB
    snowballstemmer-2.1.0      |     pyhd3eb1b0_0          62 KB
    sortedcollections-2.1.0    |     pyhd3eb1b0_0          12 KB
    sortedcontainers-2.3.0     |     pyhd3eb1b0_0          26 KB
    soupsieve-2.1              |     pyhd3eb1b0_0          31 KB
    sphinx-3.4.3               |     pyhd3eb1b0_0         1.1 MB
    sphinxcontrib-websupport-1.2.4|             py_0          34 KB
    spyder-4.2.0               |   py38hecd8cb5_0         5.7 MB
    spyder-kernels-1.10.1      |   py38hecd8cb5_0         101 KB
    sqlalchemy-1.3.21          |   py38h9ed2024_0         1.5 MB
    sqlite-3.33.0              |       hffcf06c_0         1.3 MB
    statsmodels-0.12.1         |   py38h9ed2024_0         8.2 MB
    sympy-1.7.1                |   py38hecd8cb5_0         8.8 MB
    tbb-2020.3                 |       h879752b_0         147 KB
    tblib-1.7.0                |             py_0          16 KB
    terminado-0.9.2            |   py38hecd8cb5_0          25 KB
    three-merge-0.1.1          |     pyhd3eb1b0_0          10 KB
    tifffile-2021.1.14         |     pyhd3eb1b0_1         126 KB
    toolz-0.11.1               |     pyhd3eb1b0_0          46 KB
    tornado-6.1                |   py38h9ed2024_0         585 KB
    tqdm-4.55.1                |     pyhd3eb1b0_0          77 KB
    traitlets-5.0.5            |             py_0          83 KB
    typed-ast-1.4.2            |   py38h9ed2024_1         183 KB
    typing_extensions-3.7.4.3  |             py_0          28 KB
    ujson-4.0.2                |   py38h23ab428_0          46 KB
    unixodbc-2.3.9             |       haf1e3a3_0         251 KB
    urllib3-1.26.2             |     pyhd3eb1b0_0         105 KB
    watchdog-0.10.4            |   py38h9ed2024_0          96 KB
    wheel-0.36.2               |     pyhd3eb1b0_0          33 KB
    wrapt-1.11.2               |   py38h9ed2024_0          45 KB
    xlrd-2.0.1                 |     pyhd3eb1b0_0          90 KB
    xlsxwriter-1.3.7           |             py_0         108 KB
    xlwings-0.21.4             |   py38hecd8cb5_0         446 KB
    zeromq-4.3.3               |       hb1e8313_3         414 KB
    zfp-0.5.5                  |       h23ab428_4         147 KB
    zipp-3.4.0                 |     pyhd3eb1b0_0          15 KB
    zope.event-4.5.0           |           py38_0         209 KB
    zope.interface-5.2.0       |   py38h9ed2024_0         281 KB
    ------------------------------------------------------------
                                           Total:       201.5 MB

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

  _anaconda_depends  pkgs/main/osx-64::_anaconda_depends-2020.07-py38_0
  appdirs            pkgs/main/noarch::appdirs-1.4.4-py_0
  argon2-cffi        pkgs/main/osx-64::argon2-cffi-20.1.0-py38haf1e3a3_1
  async_generator    pkgs/main/noarch::async_generator-1.10-py_0
  black              pkgs/main/noarch::black-19.10b0-py_0
  brotli             pkgs/main/osx-64::brotli-1.0.9-hb1e8313_2
  brunsli            pkgs/main/osx-64::brunsli-0.1-h23ab428_0
  charls             pkgs/main/osx-64::charls-2.1.0-hb1e8313_2
  giflib             pkgs/main/osx-64::giflib-5.1.4-h1de35cc_1
  imagecodecs        pkgs/main/osx-64::imagecodecs-2021.1.11-py38h2ea9c00_1
  iniconfig          pkgs/main/noarch::iniconfig-1.1.1-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  jupyterlab_pygmen~ pkgs/main/noarch::jupyterlab_pygments-0.1.2-py_0
  jupyterlab_widgets pkgs/main/noarch::jupyterlab_widgets-1.0.0-pyhd3eb1b0_1
  jxrlib             pkgs/main/osx-64::jxrlib-1.1-haf1e3a3_2
  lerc               pkgs/main/osx-64::lerc-2.2.1-h23ab428_0
  libaec             pkgs/main/osx-64::libaec-1.0.4-hb1e8313_1
  libdeflate         pkgs/main/osx-64::libdeflate-1.7-h9ed2024_5
  libllvm10          pkgs/main/osx-64::libllvm10-10.0.1-h76017ad_5
  libwebp            pkgs/main/osx-64::libwebp-1.0.1-hd73b212_0
  libzopfli          pkgs/main/osx-64::libzopfli-1.0.3-hb1e8313_0
  mypy_extensions    pkgs/main/osx-64::mypy_extensions-0.4.3-py38_0
  nbclient           pkgs/main/noarch::nbclient-0.5.1-py_0
  nest-asyncio       pkgs/main/noarch::nest-asyncio-1.4.3-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  openjpeg           pkgs/main/osx-64::openjpeg-2.3.0-hb95cd4c_1
  pathspec           pkgs/main/noarch::pathspec-0.7.0-py_0
  pyerfa             pkgs/main/osx-64::pyerfa-1.7.1.1-py38h9ed2024_1
  pyls-black         pkgs/main/noarch::pyls-black-0.4.6-hd3eb1b0_0
  pyls-spyder        pkgs/main/noarch::pyls-spyder-0.3.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  three-merge        pkgs/main/noarch::three-merge-0.1.1-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  tifffile           pkgs/main/noarch::tifffile-2021.1.14-pyhd3eb1b0_1
  typed-ast          pkgs/main/osx-64::typed-ast-1.4.2-py38h9ed2024_1
  zfp                pkgs/main/osx-64::zfp-0.5.5-h23ab428_4

The following packages will be UPDATED:

  anaconda-navigator                          1.9.12-py38_0 --> 1.10.0-py38_0
  anaconda-project                               0.8.4-py_0 --> 0.9.1-pyhd3eb1b0_1
  appnope                                   0.1.0-py38_1001 --> 0.1.2-py38hecd8cb5_1001
  asn1crypto         pkgs/main/osx-64::asn1crypto-1.3.0-py~ --> pkgs/main/noarch::asn1crypto-1.4.0-py_0
  astropy                        4.0.1.post1-py38h01d97ff_1 --> 4.2-py38h9ed2024_0
  attrs                                         19.3.0-py_0 --> 20.3.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  autopep8                                       1.5.3-py_0 --> 1.5.4-py_0
  babel                                          2.8.0-py_0 --> 2.9.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  backports.shutil_~ pkgs/main/osx-64::backports.shutil_ge~ --> pkgs/main/noarch::backports.shutil_get_terminal_size-1.0.0-pyhd3eb1b0_3
  beautifulsoup4     pkgs/main/osx-64::beautifulsoup4-4.9.~ --> pkgs/main/noarch::beautifulsoup4-4.9.3-pyha847dfd_0
  bitarray                             1.4.0-py38haf1e3a3_0 --> 1.6.3-py38h9ed2024_1
  bleach                                         3.1.5-py_0 --> 3.2.2-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  blosc                                   1.19.0-hab81aa3_0 --> 1.20.1-hab81aa3_0
  bokeh                                        2.1.1-py38_0 --> 2.2.3-py38_0
  brotlipy                          0.7.0-py38haf1e3a3_1000 --> 0.7.0-py38h9ed2024_1003
  ca-certificates                               2020.6.24-0 --> 2021.1.19-hecd8cb5_0
  certifi                                  2020.6.20-py38_0 --> 2020.12.5-py38hecd8cb5_0
  cffi                                1.14.0-py38hc512035_1 --> 1.14.4-py38h2125817_0
  chardet                                   3.0.4-py38_1003 --> 4.0.0-py38hecd8cb5_1003
  cloudpickle                                    1.5.0-py_0 --> 1.6.0-py_0
  colorama                                       0.4.3-py_0 --> 0.4.4-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  conda-build                                 3.20.0-py38_0 --> 3.21.4-py38hecd8cb5_0
  conda-package-han~                   1.6.1-py38h1de35cc_0 --> 1.7.2-py38h22f3db7_0
  cryptography                         2.9.2-py38ha12b0ac_0 --> 3.3.1-py38hbcfaee0_0
  cytoolz                             0.10.1-py38h1de35cc_0 --> 0.11.0-py38haf1e3a3_0
  dask                                          2.20.0-py_0 --> 2020.12.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  dask-core                                     2.20.0-py_0 --> 2020.12.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  dbus                                   1.13.16-h18a8e69_0 --> 1.13.18-h18a8e69_0
  distributed                                 2.20.0-py38_0 --> 2021.1.0-py38hecd8cb5_0
  expat                                    2.2.9-hb1e8313_2 --> 2.2.10-hb1e8313_2
  filelock                                      3.0.12-py_0 --> 3.0.12-pyhd3eb1b0_1
  flake8                                         3.8.3-py_0 --> 3.8.4-py_0
  freetype                                2.10.2-ha233b18_0 --> 2.10.4-ha233b18_0
  fsspec                                         0.7.4-py_0 --> 0.8.3-py_0
  gevent                              20.6.2-py38haf1e3a3_0 --> 21.1.1-py38h9ed2024_1
  glib                                    2.65.0-hc5f4afa_0 --> 2.66.1-h9bbe63b_0
  greenlet                            0.4.16-py38haf1e3a3_0 --> 0.4.17-py38haf1e3a3_0
  importlib-metadata pkgs/main/osx-64::importlib-metadata-~ --> pkgs/main/noarch::importlib-metadata-2.0.0-py_1
  importlib_metadata                                1.7.0-0 --> 2.0.0-1
  intervaltree                                   3.0.2-py_1 --> 3.1.0-py_0
  ipykernel                            5.3.2-py38h5ca1d4c_0 --> 5.3.4-py38h5ca1d4c_0
  ipython                             7.16.1-py38h5ca1d4c_0 --> 7.19.0-py38h01d92e1_1
  ipython_genutils   pkgs/main/osx-64::ipython_genutils-0.~ --> pkgs/main/noarch::ipython_genutils-0.2.0-pyhd3eb1b0_1
  ipywidgets                                     7.5.1-py_0 --> 7.6.3-pyhd3eb1b0_1
  isort               pkgs/main/osx-64::isort-4.3.21-py38_0 --> pkgs/main/noarch::isort-5.6.4-py_0
  jedi                                        0.17.1-py38_0 --> 0.17.2-py38hecd8cb5_1
  joblib                                        0.16.0-py_0 --> 1.0.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  jsonschema         pkgs/main/osx-64::jsonschema-3.2.0-py~ --> pkgs/main/noarch::jsonschema-3.2.0-py_2
  jupyter_client                                 6.1.6-py_0 --> 6.1.7-py_0
  jupyter_console                                6.1.0-py_0 --> 6.2.0-py_0
  jupyter_core                                 4.6.3-py38_0 --> 4.7.0-py38hecd8cb5_0
  jupyterlab                                     2.1.5-py_0 --> 2.2.6-py_0
  keyring                                     21.2.1-py38_0 --> 21.8.0-py38hecd8cb5_0
  kiwisolver                           1.2.0-py38h04f5b5a_0 --> 1.3.0-py38h23ab428_0
  lazy-object-proxy                    1.4.3-py38h1de35cc_0 --> 1.4.3-py38h9ed2024_2
  libxml2                                 2.9.10-h3b9e6c8_1 --> 2.9.10-h7cdb67c_3
  llvmlite                            0.33.0-py38ha11be7d_1 --> 0.34.0-py38h739e7dc_4
  locket                                       0.2.0-py38_1 --> 0.2.1-py38hecd8cb5_1
  lxml                                 4.5.2-py38h63b7cb6_0 --> 4.6.2-py38h26b266a_0
  lz4-c                                    1.9.2-h0a44026_0 --> 1.9.3-h23ab428_0
  matplotlib                                        3.2.2-0 --> 3.3.2-hecd8cb5_0
  matplotlib-base                      3.2.2-py38h5670ca0_0 --> 3.3.2-py38h181983e_0
  mkl_fft                              1.1.0-py38hc64f4ea_0 --> 1.2.0-py38hc64f4ea_0
  mock                                           4.0.2-py_0 --> 4.0.3-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  more-itertools                                 8.4.0-py_0 --> 8.6.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  msgpack-python                       1.0.0-py38h04f5b5a_1 --> 1.0.1-py38hf7b0b51_0
  nbconvert                                    5.6.1-py38_1 --> 6.0.7-py38_0
  nbformat                                       5.0.7-py_0 --> 5.1.2-pyhd3eb1b0_1
  networkx                                         2.4-py_1 --> 2.5-py_0
  nose               pkgs/main/osx-64::nose-1.3.7-py38_1004 --> pkgs/main/noarch::nose-1.3.7-pyhd3eb1b0_1006
  notebook                                     6.0.3-py38_0 --> 6.2.0-py38hecd8cb5_0
  numba                               0.50.1-py38h959d312_1 --> 0.51.2-py38h6440ff4_1
  numexpr                              2.7.1-py38hce01a72_0 --> 2.7.2-py38h16bde0e_0
  numpy                               1.18.5-py38h1da2735_0 --> 1.19.2-py38h456fd55_0
  numpy-base                          1.18.5-py38h3304bdc_0 --> 1.19.2-py38hcfb5961_0
  numpydoc                                       1.1.0-py_0 --> 1.1.0-pyhd3eb1b0_1
  openpyxl                                       3.0.4-py_0 --> 3.0.6-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  openssl                                 1.1.1g-h1de35cc_0 --> 1.1.1i-h9ed2024_0
  packaging                                       20.4-py_0 --> 20.8-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  pandas                               1.0.5-py38h959d312_0 --> 1.2.1-py38hb2f4e1b_0
  pandoc                                             2.10-0 --> 2.11-h0dc7051_0
  pandocfilters                                1.4.2-py38_1 --> 1.4.3-py38hecd8cb5_1
  path                                        13.1.0-py38_0 --> 15.0.1-py38hecd8cb5_0
  path.py                                          12.4.0-0 --> 12.5.0-0
  pathlib2                                     2.3.5-py38_1 --> 2.3.5-py38hecd8cb5_2
  pexpect            pkgs/main/osx-64::pexpect-4.8.0-py38_1 --> pkgs/main/noarch::pexpect-4.8.0-pyhd3eb1b0_3
  pickleshare        pkgs/main/osx-64::pickleshare-0.7.5-p~ --> pkgs/main/noarch::pickleshare-0.7.5-pyhd3eb1b0_1003
  pillow                               7.2.0-py38ha54b6ba_0 --> 8.1.0-py38h5270095_0
  pip                                         20.1.1-py38_1 --> 20.3.3-py38hecd8cb5_0
  pkginfo                                    1.5.0.1-py38_0 --> 1.7.0-py38hecd8cb5_0
  prometheus_client                              0.8.0-py_0 --> 0.9.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  prompt-toolkit                                 3.0.5-py_0 --> 3.0.8-py_0
  prompt_toolkit                                    3.0.5-0 --> 3.0.8-0
  psutil                               5.7.0-py38h1de35cc_0 --> 5.7.2-py38haf1e3a3_0
  ptyprocess         pkgs/main/osx-64::ptyprocess-0.6.0-py~ --> pkgs/main/noarch::ptyprocess-0.7.0-pyhd3eb1b0_2
  py                                             1.9.0-py_0 --> 1.10.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  pycurl                            7.43.0.5-py38ha12b0ac_0 --> 7.43.0.6-py38hddc9c9b_0
  pydocstyle                                     5.0.2-py_0 --> 5.1.1-py_0
  pygments                                       2.6.1-py_0 --> 2.7.4-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  pylint                                       2.5.3-py38_0 --> 2.6.0-py38_0
  pyopenssl                                     19.1.0-py_1 --> 20.0.1-pyhd3eb1b0_1
  pyrsistent                          0.16.0-py38h1de35cc_0 --> 0.17.3-py38haf1e3a3_0
  pytest                                       5.4.3-py38_0 --> 6.2.1-py38hecd8cb5_0
  python                                   3.8.3-h26836e1_2 --> 3.8.5-h26836e1_1
  python-jsonrpc-se~                             0.3.4-py_1 --> 0.4.0-py_0
  python-language-s~ pkgs/main/osx-64::python-language-ser~ --> pkgs/main/noarch::python-language-server-0.36.2-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  python.app                                      2-py38_10 --> 3-py38h9ed2024_0
  pytz                                          2020.1-py_0 --> 2020.5-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  pywavelets                           1.1.1-py38h1de35cc_0 --> 1.1.1-py38haf1e3a3_2
  pyyaml                               5.3.1-py38haf1e3a3_1 --> 5.4.1-py38h9ed2024_1
  pyzmq                               19.0.1-py38hb1e8313_1 --> 20.0.0-py38h23ab428_1
  qtawesome                                      0.7.2-py_0 --> 1.0.1-py_0
  qtconsole                                      4.7.5-py_0 --> 0.11.1-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  send2trash         pkgs/main/osx-64::send2trash-1.5.0-py~ --> pkgs/main/noarch::send2trash-1.5.0-pyhd3eb1b0_1
  setuptools                                  49.2.0-py38_0 --> 51.3.3-py38hecd8cb5_4
  singledispatch     pkgs/main/osx-64::singledispatch-3.4.~ --> pkgs/main/noarch::singledispatch-3.4.0.3-py_1001
  snowballstemmer                                2.0.0-py_0 --> 2.1.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  sortedcollections                              1.2.1-py_0 --> 2.1.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  sortedcontainers                               2.2.2-py_0 --> 2.3.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  soupsieve                                      2.0.1-py_0 --> 2.1-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  sphinx                                         3.1.2-py_0 --> 3.4.3-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  sphinxcontrib-web~                             1.2.3-py_0 --> 1.2.4-py_0
  spyder                                       4.1.4-py38_0 --> 4.2.0-py38hecd8cb5_0
  spyder-kernels                               1.9.2-py38_0 --> 1.10.1-py38hecd8cb5_0
  sqlalchemy                          1.3.18-py38haf1e3a3_0 --> 1.3.21-py38h9ed2024_0
  sqlite                                  3.32.3-hffcf06c_0 --> 3.33.0-hffcf06c_0
  statsmodels                         0.11.1-py38haf1e3a3_0 --> 0.12.1-py38h9ed2024_0
  sympy                                        1.6.1-py38_0 --> 1.7.1-py38hecd8cb5_0
  tbb                                     2020.0-h04f5b5a_0 --> 2020.3-h879752b_0
  tblib                                          1.6.0-py_0 --> 1.7.0-py_0
  terminado                                    0.8.3-py38_0 --> 0.9.2-py38hecd8cb5_0
  toolz                                         0.10.0-py_0 --> 0.11.1-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  tornado                              6.0.4-py38h1de35cc_1 --> 6.1-py38h9ed2024_0
  tqdm                                          4.47.0-py_0 --> 4.55.1-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  traitlets          pkgs/main/osx-64::traitlets-4.3.3-py3~ --> pkgs/main/noarch::traitlets-5.0.5-py_0
  typing_extensions                            3.7.4.2-py_0 --> 3.7.4.3-py_0
  ujson                                 1.35-py38h1de35cc_0 --> 4.0.2-py38h23ab428_0
  unixodbc                                 2.3.7-h1de35cc_0 --> 2.3.9-haf1e3a3_0
  urllib3                                       1.25.9-py_0 --> 1.26.2-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  watchdog                            0.10.3-py38haf1e3a3_0 --> 0.10.4-py38h9ed2024_0
  wheel               pkgs/main/osx-64::wheel-0.34.2-py38_0 --> pkgs/main/noarch::wheel-0.36.2-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  xlrd                                           1.2.0-py_0 --> 2.0.1-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  xlsxwriter                                     1.2.9-py_0 --> 1.3.7-py_0
  xlwings                                     0.19.5-py38_0 --> 0.21.4-py38hecd8cb5_0
  zeromq                                   4.3.2-hb1e8313_2 --> 4.3.3-hb1e8313_3
  zipp                                           3.1.0-py_0 --> 3.4.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  zope.event                                     4.4-py38_0 --> 4.5.0-py38_0
  zope.interface                       4.7.1-py38h1de35cc_0 --> 5.2.0-py38h9ed2024_0

The following packages will be SUPERSEDED by a higher-priority channel:

  six                     pkgs/main/noarch::six-1.15.0-py_0 --> pkgs/main/osx-64::six-1.15.0-py38hecd8cb5_0

The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:

  anaconda                                   2020.07-py38_0 --> custom-py38_1
  backports                                        1.0-py_2 --> 1.0-pyhd3eb1b0_2
  backports.functoo~                             1.6.1-py_0 --> 1.6.1-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  backports.tempfile                               1.0-py_1 --> 1.0-pyhd3eb1b0_1
  click                                          7.1.2-py_0 --> 7.1.2-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  cython                             0.29.21-py38hb1e8313_0 --> 0.29.21-py38h23ab428_0
  glob2                                            0.7-py_0 --> 0.7-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  idna                                            2.10-py_0 --> 2.10-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  jinja2                                        2.11.2-py_0 --> 2.11.2-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  lzo                                       2.10-h1de35cc_2 --> 2.10-haf1e3a3_2
  mkl-service                          2.3.0-py38hfbe908c_0 --> 2.3.0-py38h9ed2024_0
  pyparsing                                      2.4.7-py_0 --> 2.4.7-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  python-libarchive~                               2.9-py_0 --> 2.9-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  wrapt                               1.11.2-py38h1de35cc_0 --> 1.11.2-py38h9ed2024_0


Proceed ([y]/n)?
```

I was wondering is there any way to easily clean up all the packages I've installed globally so that I can start fresh with virtual environments? Otherwise is there any way I can update everything without the version conflicts?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity it's my first time posting here. I've edited my post to include the commands I've run and the output I get when trying to update packages. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Conda does not create the alias `pip3`, which means that you are not installing into the Conda environment. To use Pip in a Conda environment you must activate the environment then use `pip install`. Ideally, Conda functions most cleanly when PATH is clear of other Python installations.